# Dynamic stack assing value to a struct inside the stack struct

Tags: c, struct

I'm having a problem in line: `novo->conta.nome_cliente = valor2;`. In this dynamic stack structure. `Empilhar` is a function to push a new element to the stack. Why i cant assign a new value to the structure inside the stack?

```
struct conta_de_luz 
{
    int cod_cliente;
    char nome_cliente[40];
};

typedef struct Item {

    struct conta_de_luz conta;

    struct Item *anterior; 
} Elemento;

void Inicializar(Elemento **topo) {

    *topo = NULL;
}

int EstaVazia(Elemento **topo) {
    if(*topo == NULL)
        return VERD;
    else
        return FALSO;
}

void Empilhar(Elemento **topo, int valor, char valor2) {

    Elemento *novo;

    novo = (Elemento *) malloc(sizeof(Elemento));

    novo->conta.cod_cliente = valor;

    novo->conta.nome_cliente = valor2;

    novo->anterior = *topo;

    *topo = novo;
}
```

Comment: `return 1` and `return 0` is a lot more sensible here. Those labels just confuse things.

Comment: It's far from clear what this code is trying to do, or even how it might be used.

Comment: In C you cannot just asssign one array to be equal to another. With C strings you *must* use functions like `strncpy` to transpose string data. `x = y` will not cut it.

Comment: Turn on or up compiler warnings and take heed of them. It will point you to obvious errors in your code. For example: `novo->conta.nome_cliente = valor2;` should give a warning as the left and right hand side types are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that line `novo->conta.nome_cliente = valor2;` assigns a `char` to something that is a string defined as `char nome_cliente[40];`.

So your function probably should have been `void Empilhar(Elemento **topo, int valor, char* valor2)`. But that would still assume the value of `valor2` remains in memory for the lifetime of `topo`.

Better would be `void Empilhar(Elemento **topo, int valor, const char* valor2)` and then use `strcpy(novo->conta.nome_cliente, valor2);`.

But this assumes `valor2` including its NULL-terminator always fits within 40 characters. If this assumption is not guaranteed it's better to duplicate the string using `strdup()`. You will then also need to `free()` this seperately this in your cleanup function.